# fetch img src when click of multiple posts have same div class and button class

Tags: jquery, html, ejs

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){

    $('.like').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reloading

        alert( $('.post-container').find('#img').attr('src'));

    });

});

</script>
```

```
<table id="posts">

    <% result.forEach(function(item){ %>

        <div class="post-container">
        <%= item.img_id%>
        <img src="<%= item.img_url %>" id="img" class="img">
        <div><%= item.user_id%> </div>
        <input type="button" name="like" id="like" value="Like" class="like">
        </div>

    <% }) %>
```

/* after executive the ejs template look like */

```
  <div class="post-container">
        1
     <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" id="img" class="img">
     <div>UID001 </div>
     <input type="button" name="like" id="1" value="Like" class="like">
  </div>

  <div class="post-container">
        2
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/03/19/38/board-361516_960_720.jpg" 
     id="img" class="img">
     <div>UID001 </div>
     <input type="button" name="like" id="2" value="Like" class="like">
  </div>
```

i want to alert img src when below like button click, currently give 1 post img src when click on on 1 or 2 post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) or [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method to find the `<img>` tag exactly:

```js
$(function(){

    $('.like').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reloading

        alert($(this).prev().prev().attr('src'));
        
        // or
        // alert($(this).parent().find('img').attr('src'));
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="post-container">
        1
     <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" id="img" class="img">
     <div>UID001 </div>
     <input type="button" name="like" id="1" value="Like" class="like">
  </div>

  <div class="post-container">
        2
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/03/19/38/board-361516_960_720.jpg" 
     id="img" class="img">
     <div>UID001 </div>
     <input type="button" name="like" id="2" value="Like" class="like">
  </div>
```

Note: Since jquery version 1.6, you can use [.prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to get `src` property value instead of `.attr()` method:

```
alert($(this).parent().find('img').prop('src'));
```